# "Proper" Asynchronous implementation

Tags: c#

I need some opinion if my code below is proper for an async process. This code only reformats text.
Please let me know if this implementation is not proper or needs some improvement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadCharacter("File 1.txt"));
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadCharacter("File 2.txt"));

    Console.WriteLine("Main Task");            
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ReadCharacter(string inputFile)
{
    string result;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFile))
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("C:\\Out--{0}",inputFile));
        Console.WriteLine("Opening file : {0}", inputFile.ToString());
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            result = sr.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --> {1}",
                                       result,Task.CurrentId.ToString()));
        } 
        Console.WriteLine("Finish {0}", inputFile);
        sr.Close(); sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com. For starters, I would say you should be a bit more consistent. Make sure you wrap `using` around all of your streams.. not just one. Use shorthand like `while (!sr.EndOfStream)`, etc. Other than that.. codereview.SE.

Comment: I would not consider this "proper" async. You'd need to use `ReadLineAsync` for that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i will move this to codereview